# Open cmd, change directory and executespecific command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to make a simple batch file to open cmd prompt, change directory to E:\ and run the following command:

**for /r %f in (*.mkv) do echo file '%~nxf' >>%~dpf\concat.txt**

although I've been able to open cmd prompt and change the directory but when I add the above mentioned command it doesn't execute. Kindly help.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double-up the `%` character when using a `for` command in a batch file.  From the `for /?` help text:

> To use the `FOR` command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`.

So try:

```
for /r %%f in (*.mkv) do echo file '%%~nxf' >>%%~dpf\concat.txt
```

Comment: Sir u mean to say that I should be doing something like this:
`for /r %%f in (*.mkv) do echo file '%~nxf' >>%~dpf\concat.txt`